# Displaying toast messages

Tags: java, android, toast

I am developing an quiz based app in that when the user clicks any of the options it should the a suitable messages such as "your ans is correct" ,"your ans is wrong".What i wanted is

```
 1. how to display that sort of messages ?or is it the only way to display such msgs ?
 2. If the user clicks wrong option the it should show the correct answer as well as the msg

here is what i have done so far but its not working giving force close!!!


public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.button1:
            Log.d("ERR", v.getTag().toString());
            if (v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("right")) 
            {
                displayAnswer();

            }
            else
            {
                errorAnswer();

            }

            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Log.d("ERR", v.getTag().toString());
            if (v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("right")) 
            {
                displayAnswer();
            }
            else
            {
                errorAnswer();

            }
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            Log.d("ERR", v.getTag().toString());
            if (v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("right")) 
            {
                displayAnswer();
            }
            else
            {
                errorAnswer();

            }
            break;

        case R.id.button4:
            Log.d("ERR", v.getTag().toString());
            if (v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("right")) 
            {
                displayAnswer();
            }
            else
            {
                errorAnswer();


            }
            break;

        case R.id.btn_next:
//          lyt_ans.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//          lyt_quest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            prev = counter;
            counter += 1;

            if (counter >= SIZE) 
            {
                Collections.shuffle(quizIndexList);
                counter = 0;
            }
            getInfoFromDB(quizIndexList.get(counter));
            reLoad();

            break;

        case R.id.btn_bck:
                getInfoFromDB(quizIndexList.get(prev));
                    reLoad();
//          counter --;




        }
    }

    private void errorAnswer() 
    {
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(SIZE);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.setText("your answer is wrong");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void displayAnswer() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lyt_quest = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_quest);
        lyt_ans = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_ans);
        lyt_quest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lyt_ans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//      TextView txt1 = null;
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(SIZE);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.setText("Your answer is correct!!");
    }
```

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Where are you setting the tag of the view v, ie the button to which u r setting the onClick()?

Comment: You need to attach the stack trace. You need to call `Toast#show` for the toast to appear. `Toast#setDuration` can only be called with `LENGTH_SHORT` or `LENGTH_LONG`.

Comment: @Rithesh: where is toast.show()

Comment: yap i have added it now _Thank you_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why don't you use

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

What you have written in your code will give you an error saying **This toast was never created using Toast.makeText()**. So it is better for you to use this method.

If you want to use custom toast message, then one thing is compulsory what you have not done in your code. After creating your **toast object**, you have to set the view to that toast using **setView(your inflated layout object)**. and then you have to invoke **toast.show()** at last. But remember, you have to get the inflated layout and pass it to **setView()**.

For more about custom toast see [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Comment: k but when the user clicks the wrong answer it should show the answer and also it should go for the next question . How can i do that??

Comment: @Ritheshm in this case pass the correct answer as a message to the toast.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar But he is using costom toast, in which he is facing problem, no doubt default will work, but in his case he is facing problem in custom toast, Giving solution of his problem you given him alternate solution.

Comment: @RobinHood I think now its ok, see my updated answer. By the way thank you for your comment.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar for that we cannot put the toast messages i guess know. We can use _dialog box_ for that right????

Comment: @Ritheshm yes you are absolutely right. Toast message is used to show a message. if you want to move to next question also, then you have to use dialog box.

Answer (score 4):

```
v.getTag()
```

I am not finding any `setTag(object)` in your code.

once you setTag() to the view, then and then only you can getTag() of the same view.

```
Log.d("ERR", v.getTag().toString());
```

`if (v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("right"))`

Error will come here before you showing `Toast`

you also missing, to view the Toast `toast.show()`

Comment: but i have written setText know

Comment: if (v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("right")) may have problem.